# How could I write a program which has different part bit version?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a scan `dll` in running process in `64 bit OS` using [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It worked perfectly for 64 bit process but for 32 bit process it couldn't do it perfectly. So I have an idea:

```
If Running_process_is_32_bit
   Scan_DLL_32bit_version
else 
   scan_DLL_64bit_version
```

I know have a way to deal with it is make two program for each task. But could I do it with only a program? If can how to make it? 
Thanks!

Comment: A dll is all 32 or all 64 bits so you will have 2 dlls. Same goes for an application.

Comment: @drescherjm When I used this program `64 bit version` scan `32 bit` process, some dll missed. When I used this program `32 bit version` scan `32 bit` process, all dll showed up.

Comment: One way is to use an #ifdef in your code to do something different for your 64 bit scan dll than your 32 bit scan dll.

Comment: @drescherjm So I still need two 2 dlls?

Comment: Yes. Because you can't have 32 bit code in a 64 bit dll or viseversa. And a 64 bit dll will not be loaded into a 32 bit process and a 32 bit will not be loaded into a 64 bit process.

Comment: @drescherjm but in 64 bit program i need both 32 bit dlls and 64 dlls because 64 bit OS can run both process bit version.

Comment: You need 2 programs then. A 32 bit application and a 64 bit application.

Comment: Native programs are fixed 32 or 64 bit, but .NET programs can be built in "neutral" mode. Only when such a program runs, it can know its bitness,